# jQuery Summernote - Get text back into editor

Tags: jquery

I got problems getting text back into the summernote editor.

I already tried (but did not work):

```
$("#EDITsummernote").innerHtml = 'test';
```

How to do that?

Comment: try this $("#editsummernote").text("teset");

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It's $("#editsummernote").code("teset");

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**Since v0.7.0** `code()` has been deprecated and removed (same story for `destroy()` method).

You must use `$(".summernote").summernote("code", "your text");`

Reference: https://summernote.org/getting-started/#get--set-code

> After v0.7.0, direct jquery methods, `destroy` and `code` were removed for avoiding conflict with other jquery libraries. You can call this methods with summernote api.

Comment: this actually seems to create a new instance of the summernote editor inside the old one...

Comment: That is right. if you have a the initialise function already, than you can still go with   `.summernote('code', contentVariable);`

Comment: @ChristopherMilne nope, if, your summernote somehow re-initiated (in my case, my original has height), it is actually because somehow your summernote("code") function is run before your original initiate code (maybe you put your  summernote("code") function in another function and accidentally call it before your original initiate code)

Answer (score 28):

```
$(".summernote").code("your text");
```

Comment: Please include a summary of what you code does and why you suggested it.

Comment: @MathieuCastets Instead of editing this post you should add the newer solution as a separate answer. You can then edit into this answer that it is outdated. See this discussion on Meta on that matter: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thank you for your advice

Comment: Try this: `$('#summernote').summernote ('code', '<b> hello world </ b>');`

Answer (score 12):

Insert Text:

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertText', 'hello world');
```

You can use this line if you want to set (paste) HTML code in editor:

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', '<b>hello world</b>');
```

[Source code](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/dist/summernote.js#L4120)

**Bonus**

Clear all editor content:

```
$('#summernote').code("");
```

Comment: Clear contents and remove all stored history, Use this: `$('#summernote').summernote('reset');` Following is the documentation: http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#reset

Answer (score 10):

To set:

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code', '<b> hello world </b>');
```

To get:

```
var get_code = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
```

Documentation: http://summernote.org/getting-started/#get--set-code

Answer (score 1):

$('#summernote').html(escape($('#summernote').summernote('code', '**some**')));

Answer (score 0):

To set text in the summernote editor:

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertText', 'hello world');
```

Comment: Does not work with  '<b> hello world </ b>', to work, look at my answer.

Comment: Your code has 1 more parentheses. Please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the Solutions works for me until I did this.

`<textarea name="description" class="form-control summernote_rpt summernote_custom"></textarea>`

Let's say you have initialized summernote something like this in which I have two classes
`.summernote_custom` was used 
`$('.summernote_rpt').summernote(options);`

when the entire page loads and when I wanted to update the summernote value using js I used
`$('.summernote_rpt').summernote('code','data');`