# Summernote: Programmatically insert in to Code view

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, summernote

I am trying to programmatically insert some html into summernote's CODE view like so:

```
var markupStr = 'hello world';
$('#summernote').summernote('code', markupStr);
```

Referencing this [summernote documentation](http://summernote.org/getting-started/#get-amp-set-code) and this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068379/jquery-summernote-get-text-back-into-editor/34289687#34289687). I would like this insertion to take place while in the CODE view, but this does not happen.

[image]

However, if I try to make this insertion (with the same code above) while in the DEFAULT non-code view it inserts as expected. And when switching to CODE view still shows as expected.

[image]

Looks like my issue may be related to this [summernote GitHub issue](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/94), but not certain.

Was wondering if any of you summernote users out there have figured out a way to programmatically insert directly in to the code view?

Answer (score 0):

Hack:

```
var markupStr = 'hello world';
$(angular.element.find("div.note-editor button.btn-codeview")[0]).click()
$('#summernote').summernote('code', markupStr);
$(angular.element.find("div.note-editor button.btn-codeview")[0]).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, this piece of code will solve the issue. You can initialize summernote in code view using codeview.activate.

```
$('.summernote').on('summernote.init', function () {
      $('.summernote').summernote('codeview.activate');
    }).summernote({
      height: 300,
      placeholder: 'Paste content here...',
      codemirror: { 
        theme: 'monokai'
      }
    });

var markupStr = 'hello world';
$('#summernote').summernote('code', markupStr);
```